# How to access span values

Tags: html

How do I access span values
     /// with this I can access  but I want to access all span values can anyone 
     help  p = summaryContainer.parentElement.firstElementChild;

```
 <div class="col-50"> 
 <div id ="orderSummary"> 
     <h2>Order summary</h2> 
 <div class ="summary-container">
    <div class ="summary"> 
       <div class="product">            
         <span>Natural Straight</span>          
         <div class="price">$95,00</div> 
         <div class="quantity"> 
         <span>1</span> 
        </div>
        <div class="total">$95,00 </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should works fine

```js
let summaryContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('summary-container')[0];
let spans = summaryContainer.getElementsByTagName("span");
let content = Array.prototype.slice.call(spans).map(span => span.innerText)

console.log(content)
```

```html
        <div class="col-50">
            <div id ="orderSummary">
                <h2>Order summary</h2>
                <div class ="summary-container">
                    <div class ="summary">
                        <div class="product">
                            <span>Natural Straight</span>
                            <div class="price">$95,00</div>
                            <div class="quantity">
                                <span>1</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="total">$95,00 </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: it is printing as undefined

Comment: @madhu how did you get `summaryContainer`? using `document.getElementsByClassName('summary-container')`?

Comment: @madhu it'll be easier to identify the problem if you can edit your question and add part of your js code.

Comment: still not able to access, I want to access them using DOM elements

Comment: @madhu I've added the code snippet to my answer, please run it to see the result. it's working fine

Comment: p = summaryContainer.parentElement.firstElementChild; I can access div = summary and after this I want to access Inside div= summary which is div=product

Comment: @madhu if you want to get all nested span, what was actually your question, you don't need to go step by step into nested divs. Please check my updated answer. It seems to me that it works as you wanted.